# How can i give CSS to HTML tag inside an Iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

Here is My [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dineshkanivu/Lt7L5fop/3/)

HTML

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
          <h1>Outer HTML</h1>    
       <iframe src="">        

             <html>

                 <head></head>
                 <body>
                     <h1>InnerHTML</h1>    

                 </body>


             </html>




        </iframe> 

    </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
html{background:green}
iframe{border:1px #fff solid; }
iframe html{background:red}
```

I would like to give css for `<html>` tag inside an iframe. How can i do that. In my Code `iframe html{background:red}` this CSS not working.

Comment: why is it inside an iframe if it is not calling an outside page?

Comment: @Martin dude i need this way Only, The Only point is How can i apply CSS to <html> inside an iframe

Comment: yes but why? The reason for iframes is that the code inside of it is in another page, I will write you an answer...

Comment: MR @Martin this is a sample code, I am using it in my Live site

Comment: I have used your sample code to give an anwser, I hope it is clear to you the structure of how this works.

Answer (score 2):

Applying css on iframe contents in cross-domain does not work.

You can try one of these:

The style of the page embedded in the iframe must be either set by including it in the child page:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="Style/simple.css" />
```

Or it can be loaded from the parent page with Javascript:

```
var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
cssLink.href = "style.css"; 
cssLink .rel = "stylesheet";
cssLink .type = "text/css"; 
frames['frame1'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for iframes is that code inside the iframe should be in another page, that is called from the outer page but not necessarily on direct show to the end user, so your iframe needs to have a page it calls - on that page that is called, then you can reference the CSS in the `<head>` section to use CSS display correctly.

Thus:

## page.htm

```
 <html>
    <head>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
    <body>
          <h1>Outer HTML</h1>    
       <iframe src="two.htm">        
        </iframe> 

    </body>
</html>
```

## stylesheet.css

```
html{
background:green
}
```

iframe{border: #fff 1px solid; }

## two.htm:

```
          <html>
                 <head>
<link href="inner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
                 <body>
                     <h1>InnerHTML</h1>    
                 </body>
             </html>
```

## inner.css

This is the style sheet that is applied ONLY to the contents of the iframe:

```
 html{
    background:red
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set background to the iframe or a class to the iframe instead..

**Css**

```
html{background:green}
iframe{border:1px #fff solid; }
iframe{background:red;}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7L5fop/4/)

Comment: Dude i want css to the <html> tag. Not iframe

Comment: then you need to inlcude the style html{background:red} inside the iframe